# Return distinct JSON array elements that exist in all rows in Oracle 19c

Tags: sql, json, oracle

## Problem

I have some data that starts off as JSON like

```json
{
  "someID": "xxx",
  "flags": ["A", "B", "C"]
}
```

that is stored in a table where flags has been extracted to store the value as a `varchar2` field called `FLAGS`

What I want to do is get a distinct list of flag values that occur in every row in the data I am selecting (which will be dynamic based on other predicates)

so if you have the above and another record with `"flags": ["A", "B", "D"]` I want `["A", "B"]` as the result

if you add a third record with `"flags" ["A", "D", "E"]` I want `["A"]`

and so on, returning only those array vales that exist on every row being considered (or null if there aren't any)

## Attempts

I can achieve this using something like

```sql
select distinct FLAG
from   MY_TABLE,
  json_table(FLAGS, '$[*]' columns FLAG path '$')
```

to get a distinct list of flags and then build some dynamic SQL that looks like

```sql
select json_arrayagg(FLAG order by FLAG)
from (
  select 'A' as FLAG, count(*) as NUM_WITHOUT
  from   MY_TABLE
  where  not json_exists(FLAGS, '$[*]?(@ == "A")')
  union all
  select 'B' as FLAG, count(*) as NUM_WITHOUT
  from   MY_TABLE
  where  not json_exists(FLAGS, '$[*]?(@ == "B")')
  -- union all for other values
)
where  NUM_WITHOUT = 0
```

which seems particularly inefficient but also relies on dynamic SQL which I would much rather avoid

Comment: json is by nature slow and ineffective to handle, a normalized table would make that much more efficient and faster

Comment: We have some large mongo documents that get integrated into other things and with recent updates JSON processing is surprisingly performant.   But even if I normalise out the flags (as the `JSON_TABLE` does above, still have the same question of how you would return the required results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the flags values, count rows by grouping them, the ones with the same number as the number of rows of the data source are the ones in every row.

```
WITH data(id, js) AS (
    SELECT 1, q'~{
  "someID": "xxx",
  "flags": ["A", "B", "C"]
}~' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, q'~{
  "someID": "xxx",
  "flags": ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
}~' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, q'~{
  "someID": "xxx",
  "flags": ["A", "E"]
}~' FROM DUAL -- UNION ALL
)
SELECT val FROM (
    SELECT d.id, t.some_id, t.val
    FROM data d,
    json_table(js,
        '$'
        columns(
            some_id PATH '$.someID',
            nested path '$.flags[*]' 
            columns (
                val PATH '$'
            )
        )
    ) t
)
GROUP BY val 
HAVING( COUNT(distinct id) = (SELECT count(id) FROM data ) )
;
```

Comment: Achieved it in a different way but the comparing the row count and the number of records returned was the key.   No idea why I was trying to make it more complicated than it needed to be